# NFS client can mount, fails to automount

Tags: centos5, automount, nfs

I have /etc/auto.master:

```
/cpy/users  /etc/auto.users --timeout=90
```

I have /etc/auto.users:

```
*   -fstype=nfs4,rw,proto=tcp,port=2049   server:/users/&
```

On an "ordinary" CentOS 5 machine, these work splendidly. On my virtual machine which has been built using "yum groupinstall core" and some minor adjustments, I get this when user myself logs in:

```
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: handle_packet: type = 3
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 136, name myself, request pid 5249
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: attempting to mount entry /cpy/users/myself
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: lookup_mount: lookup(program): looking up myself
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: lookup(program): lookup for myself failed
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: ioctl_send_fail: token = 136
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: handle_packet: type = 3
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 137, name myself, request pid 5249
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: failed to mount /cpy/users/myself
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: attempting to mount entry /cpy/users/myself
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: ioctl_send_fail: token = 137
Apr 14 09:33:29 testing automount[5240]: failed to mount /cpy/users/myself
```

There is no network traffic against the NFS server when this occurs.

I realize that it can be a bit difficult to know exactly what is wrong, but any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What happens when you try to mount the directory by hand, e.g. `mkdir /tmp/myself; mount -t nfs4 server:/users/myself /tmp/myself`? If it fails, can you run `tcpdump` during a mount attempt and post the relevant parts? What VM technology are you using, and what's your VM network topology? My first guesses would be firewalls or other obstacles to NFS or possibly portmap.

Comment: No, mounting myself's homedir by hand somewhere else in the VM works fine. It's a Xen HVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gn! Answer to myself:

```
chmod -x /etc/auto.master /etc/auto.users
```

Problem solved. How's that for an obscure error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your `/etc/auto.users` file just a little:

```
*   -fstype=nfs4   server:/users/&
```

The rw flag should be controlled by the server export anyway, the tcp/port stuff should be left default unless you have specifically hacked it to be different.

Comment: The & is necessary to reference whatever the wildcard in the first field matched, so that /cpy/users/foo maps to server:/users/foo.